# np.matmul changes the dimensions of my matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, transpose

I have the following arrays with the following dimensions:

A is (2 x 1 x 10). In general form, (N x 1 x D)

B is (30 x 10)

I need to make the dot product of both of them by using `np.matmul`, in such a way that `matmul` multiplies the N matrices with shape 1xD of A, with the other argument, B.

Looking at the dimensions of A and B, one should think that I need to make the transpose of B before multiplying, in order to be possible to do the product.

```
B_transpose = np.transpose(B)
```

Now, `B_transpose` is (10 x 30)

But when I do `matmul`:

```
output = np.matmul(A, B_transpose)
```

It gives me an error:

> ValueError: shapes (2,1,10) and (2,1,30) not aligned: 10 (dim 2) != 1 (dim 1)

Actually, it changes the B_transpose dimensions, and I do not know why. It should be (10 x 30). I checked it with `B_transpose.shape`, and it's that. But when multiplying, it converts it to (2 x 1 x 30). Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: would help if you added test input and expected output

Comment: Can you post your full error code? I can't reproduce your error

Comment: I think something else in your code has changed `B_transpose`.  It's not the `matmul` operation.  No way is it going to change a (10,30) to (2,1,30) shape.  They don't even have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it comfortably with `numpy.einsum` as far as I know:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((2, 1, 10))
B = np.random.random((30,10))

C=np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl', A, B)
print(C)

print("shape of A: "+ str(A.shape))
print("shape of B: "+str(B.shape))
print("shape of C: "+str(C.shape))
```

Output:

```
[[[2.24297933 1.90535058 1.64265642 2.017492   1.64335181 1.92980808
   2.49041745 3.34348547 1.99242493 2.48508664 1.46283295 2.32082231
   2.68276213 1.58709381 1.22955766 1.46049189 1.66621528 1.62563277
   2.0199153  2.06292694 1.74791187 2.80959004 1.66948659 1.87064246
   1.4671402  1.83211074 1.70360887 2.13277365 2.0971552  1.89335019]]

 [[3.05604669 3.21934434 1.77297603 2.61009216 2.94784787 3.44622224
   3.13340867 5.00977942 3.55128091 3.75517549 2.71985505 3.84420034
   4.03311806 2.56002937 1.726476   2.53251146 3.43982974 2.2561291
   3.63013679 3.23935523 2.84565586 4.21606203 2.49771182 3.11465742
   2.48485314 3.62590865 2.96567419 3.00654852 3.20750017 3.1852716 ]]]
shape of A: (2, 1, 10)
shape of B: (30, 10)
shape of C: (2, 1, 30)
```

Comment: `D = A @ B.T` produces the same thing.